# JDK9 module - maven - how to import e.g. org.apache.http package?

Tags: java, maven

Working with a JDK9 module I use the Apache Http packge.

How can I import that "Apache Http" Maven dependency in my module?

In my Maven file (with JDK8) I have:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

What should I add to my existing module-info.java?

```
module module1 {
    // ??? requires org.apache.http;
    exports com.hello;
}
```

My source file contains code like:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet("http://example.org");
request.addHeader("User-Agent", "Chrome");
```

The <build> settings are OK. Without the org.apache.http the multi module applicadtion works fine.

Comment: If you like to use module-info.java you have to use JDK 9!! furthermore the `module-info.java` should be located into `src/main/java` ..apart from that you should check if the httpclient contains a module definition file (module-info.class)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of @khmarbaise could help certainly: checking the module-info.java/class file. In this case there were no module-info files.

For this situation, I found the module names via [the maven package page](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents), the [package info](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/dependency-info.html) and the [news/changes](https://hc.apache.org/news.html). You can find more on the module name there. This looks like an automatic module. Correct?

Another approach is checking the names of the external libraries - or jar files. You should use the JAR file name without the version. So, sqlite-jdbc-version.jar can be imported via a 'requires sqlite.jdbc'.

So, in my case I had to add:

```
module module1 {
    requires httpclient;  // <-- added this line
    requires httpcore;    // <-- added this line
    exports com.hello;
}
```